# ReactJS doesn't work in AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I am working on Angular JS project. I am trying to make reactjs components  and trying to render them inside angular view. But it is not working.

E.g.

If I write below code inside the angular template. Nothing happens.

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

But if I write it outside the angular template. It works.

Why so? And how can I get it working in AngularJS view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a bridge of reactjs to angularjs. i suppose you can use ngReact.

In fact when you do calls to js which modifies the DOM, you have to set this code in an angularjs directive in order to execute the js once the view is loaded.

There are lots of bridges to angularjs, in which the directives are defined.